# How can set the path to config-file mozilla.cfg on local disk or on lan?

Tags: firefox

I use autoconf.js in path .../Mozilla Firefox/defaults/pref/ with

pref("general.config.obscure_value", 0);
pref("general.config.filename","mozilla.cfg");

But i want to use lan or local path for mozilla.cfg. Like this "D:/mozilla.cfg" etc.

When i start firefox with this autoconf.js

pref("general.config.obscure_value", 0);
pref("general.config.filename","C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/mozilla.cfg");

It returns error with mozilla.cfg

Answer (score 0):

From what I've read it sounds like the `mozilla.cfg` file has to be in the Firefox program folder. You might be able to work around that limitation by making a hard link to it at another location there.